# Implementation of excel's ROUND function

Tags: excel, language-agnostic, fortran

How would you implement a ROUND function:

```
ROUND(value, number of digits)
pi=3.14159265358979323
so, for example, ROUND(pi, 3) = 3.142
```

if you had these functions at your disposal:
AINT - truncates a value to a whole number
ANINT - calculates the nearest whole number
NINT - returns the nearest integer to the argument

or never minding the above functions, how is floating ROUND done at all ?

Comment: From this question I'm not sure if you are asking:
1.) How Excel's rounding function works?
2.) How to implement a rounding function using primitives?

Please clarify what specifically you wanted to know? 

Also if you meant #2 then it might be helpful for you to know that there are many types of rounding: http://www.diycalculator.com/sp-round.shtml You didn't really specify which one?

Comment: I'm trying to implement rounding function (from basic school math, I believe it to be Round-Half-Up, from your list) using intrinsic functions above. I never understood why people need to invent something new (like 10 types of "rounding") and then call it by name of something that existed for hundreds of years - rounding. Mathematicians defined it a long time ago. If you're gonna change the definiton, name it something else. Soon they're gonna make a new definition for adding scalars.

Comment: Oh, yes, before I forget. I do admire people who have the character to tell why they're downvoting a valid question. Really tells something about a person.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to worry about overflow, here's how:

```
ROUND(value, nod) = NINT(value * POWER(10, nod)) / POWER(10, nod)
```

Otherwise you need to take care of the integer part and the float part separately.

Comment: @Oorang: In case of a generic ROUND() function, definitely. If you are application specific, you could, for example, know in advance that both value and nod are below certain thresholds, which will guarantee that the above formula does not overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume, excuse my pseudo-code

```
function Round(value, num){
    numsToSave = POWER(10, num);
    value *= numsToSave ; //Get the numbers we don't want rounded on the left side of the floating point
    value = AINT( ANINT(value) );
    value /= numsToSave;

    return value;
}
```

or

```
function Round(value, num){
    numsToSave = POWER(10, num);
    value *= numsToSave ; //Get the numbers we don't want rounded on the left side of the floating point
    value = NINT(value);
    value /= numsToSave;

    return value;
}
```

Comment: I presume you meant power instead of multiplication in the first line of your function.

Comment: Yeah, didn't realize the math... Gimme my morning coffee :p